# How to verify / compare / equal BCrypt hashed Password with a given Password in Quarkus / Wildfly

Tags: security, jpa, wildfly, quarkus

I have implemented `basic auth` using security with jpa. All my REST-Endpoints can now verify the `Authorization` header of a client request.
The verfication of the password is done by the framework. Now i need to be able to verify a Password with the stored password hash.

With the default configuration the user password is stored as hash with the function `BcryptUtil.bcryptHash(String password)`. How can i check
if a given password string matches the stored bcrypt hash value?

- Source: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jpa

Comment: Actually you can just use BCryptUtil.matches(plainText, hash) to do just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small utility class that verifies as password string with a bycrpt password hash.

```
import org.wildfly.security.password.Password;
import org.wildfly.security.password.PasswordFactory;
import org.wildfly.security.password.WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider;
import org.wildfly.security.password.interfaces.BCryptPassword;
import org.wildfly.security.password.util.ModularCrypt;

import io.quarkus.elytron.security.common.BcryptUtil;

public class SecurityUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String bCryptPasswordHash = BcryptUtil.bcryptHash("Password_1");
        String passwordToVerify = "Password_1";

        System.out.println(verifyBCryptPassword(bCryptPasswordHash, passwordToVerify)); // -> true

        System.out.println(verifyBCryptPassword(bCryptPasswordHash, "NotPassword_1")); // --> false

    }

    public static boolean verifyBCryptPassword(String bCryptPasswordHash, String passwordToVerify) throws Exception {

        WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider provider = new WildFlyElytronPasswordProvider();

        // 1. Create a BCrypt Password Factory
        PasswordFactory passwordFactory = PasswordFactory.getInstance(BCryptPassword.ALGORITHM_BCRYPT, provider);

        // 2. Decode the hashed user password
        Password userPasswordDecoded = ModularCrypt.decode(bCryptPasswordHash);

        // 3. Translate the decoded user password object to one which is consumable by this factory.
        Password userPasswordRestored = passwordFactory.translate(userPasswordDecoded);

        // Verify existing user password you want to verify
        return passwordFactory.verify(userPasswordRestored, passwordToVerify.toCharArray());

    }
}
```